# Unable to intent string value inside StartActivityForResult method

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing location to start activity for result method. place is a string , declared as String place.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("location",place);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TRUE);
```

Inside start activity for result I tried to retrieve its value using these 2 ways, but none of them is working.

```
final String place = data.getStringExtra("location");
final String place = data.getExtras().getString("location");
```

This is how method looks like

```
 public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_TRUE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri url = data.getData();
            final String place = data.getStringExtra("location");
            StorageReference filepath = mstorage.child("photos").child(url.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(url).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @O
```

Comment: Is **place** an object or String?

Comment: place is a a string

Comment: The intent data you are getting inside  onActivityResult is different

Comment: Why are you passing the location when you have the location in the same activity.

Comment: By using startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) you can start another Activity and then **receive a result from that Activity in the onActivityResult()** method. Do you need that or do you need to sending data to anotherActivity?

Comment: so basically, I have 5 buttons and inside onClickListener, each button is generation different arrayIndex. I have to pass this Index/Location to StartActivityForResult.

This location/Index value will be different based on the button user clicks.

Comment: @sohan shetty , can you explain how the intent data is different?

Comment: @user7327850 you are doing it in the wrong way! Do you want to know start activity for result or intent :)

Comment: I don't want to start a new activity

Comment: I want to pass a string to onActivityResult

Comment: @user7327850 why you want to pass that to on activity result? its in the same activity that you have your data

Comment: i will call this method 5 times, from different buttons

Comment: Simple..Initialize a static variable and update each time when you click a button..and use that value in your onActivityResult.

Comment: buttonA location is Image1
buttonB location is image2

Comment: Is there a way we can pass string through intent to OnActivityMethod?

Comment: @user7327850 We use Intent to pass value from one activity to another activity, not on the same activity.

Comment: All the buttons are inside fragments oncreateview method.... 
Each button will start on ActivityMethod with its location value... whats wrong in passing a string with intent?

Answer (score 0):

you can declare one `global variable` in that `activity` and assign some specific value which you want to pass to the `onActivityResult()` you can easily access that value if you declared it globally something like this:

```
String PLACE;
...
....

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        PLACE = place;
        //intent.putExtra("location",place);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TRUE);
```

in this case the value of PLACE will be different for each button click:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String PLACE;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xx);



    Btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            PLACE = place;
            //intent.putExtra("location",place);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TRUE);
        }
    });

    Btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            PLACE = place;
            //intent.putExtra("location",place);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TRUE);
        }
    });

    Btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            PLACE = place;
            //intent.putExtra("location",place);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TRUE);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: buttonA has location 1
buttonB has location 2
buttonC has location 3

I want to call onActivity for result from each of these buttons and have to pass location value

Comment: this wont work, because place value is different for each button

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `final String place = data.getStringExtra("location");` but data does not contain key with name 'location' as no one has sets it.

It is only set when you open Gallery not the other way around!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("location",place);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TRUE);
```

Btw you already have the location value is activity itself why not to use it!

Comment: Place Value for buttonA is image1 , place Value for buttonB is image2.

Comment: I am calling onActvitystartMethod from these button , so I want to send different location values to onActivity method depending on which button is clicked

Comment: What I get from your code is you are trying to open gallery from your application and passing data to it with a key "location" right ? When you select an image it would set the result (image location and other required data ) call the onActivtyResult method be called in the same activity!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not properly understand the concept! This might help you to understand **startActivityForResult**.Then see the answer below after this explanation!

By using `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)` you can **start** another Activity and then **receive a result** from that Activity in the `onActivityResult()` method.So `onActivityResult()` is from where you start the another Activity.

**Example**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        // Use a unique request code for each use case 
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE = 0x9988; 

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Create an Intent to start AnotherActivity
            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);

            // Start AnotherActivity with the request code
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE);
        }

        //-------- When a result is returned from another Activity onActivityResult is called.--------- //
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // First we need to check if the requestCode matches the one we used.
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE) {

                // The resultCode is set by the AnotherActivity
                // By convention RESULT_OK means that what ever
                // AnotherActivity did was successful
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Get the result from the returned Intent
                    final String result = data.getStringExtra(AnotherActivity.EXTRA_DATA);

                    // Use the data - in this case, display it in a Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // AnotherActivity was not successful. No data to retrieve.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`AnotherActivity`  <- This the the one we use to send data to `MainActivity`

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

        // Constant used to identify data sent between Activities.
        public static final String EXTRA_DATA = "EXTRA_DATA";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

            final View button = findViewById(R.id.button);
            // When this button is clicked we want to return a result
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Create a new Intent as container for the result
                    final Intent data = new Intent();

                    // Add the required data to be returned to the MainActivity
                    data.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, "Some interesting data!");

                    // Set the resultCode to Activity.RESULT_OK to 
                    // indicate a success and attach the Intent
                    // which contains our result data
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data); 

                    // With finish() we close the AnotherActivity to 
                    // return to MainActivity
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // When the user hits the back button set the resultCode 
            // to Activity.RESULT_CANCELED to indicate a failure
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

---

And for your task you don't need above way it's for your knowledge, do like below

```
 <Button
     android:onClick="gatherResults"  <---  method name in your class
     android:id="@+id/button_id_one"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Have your buttons as you want!!  and they point to a method called `gatherResults`like the above one, then filter which one got clicked using their ID

now write that method in your class,

```
 public  void gatherResults(View view){
        // Perform action on click
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_id_one:
                //DO what you want for specific id button_id_one

                break;
            case R.id.button_id_two:
                //DO what you want specific id button_id_two
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see, thanks . I will  remove onActivity start method.. will try this tomorrow and will update you. Too late here.. thanks & good night

Comment: @user7327850 if you are using a fragment use this `gatherResults` in its parent's Activity class not inside the fragment

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the value in the intent of the `activity` that you are launching. So you can get this value in that new activity only. If you want this value in current activity then just maintain a global variable and on click of your buttons update it's value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

In Fragment:-

```
View v;
public static String Place;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

//Initialize your buttons

 btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Place=yourPlace;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, your_Request_code);
        }
    });

 btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Place=yourPlace;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, your_Request_code);
        }
    });

 btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Place=yourPlace;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, your_Request_code);
        }
    });

}
```

In Activity:-

```
String str_place;

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {          
               str_place=yourFragment.Place;
               //Do your stuff here and use this place object where you want
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you :-) :-)